# Memory deallocation in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, memory-management, typescript

I have a variable `oneDay` for which I have assigned an integer number

```
 var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
```

I'm releasing the memory occupied by `oneDay` using the below syntax at the end of the function termination in which the code has been declared.

```
 var oneDay=null;
```

The error that I'm getting :

> error TS2134: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same
>   type.  Variable 'oneDay ' must be of type 'Date', but here has type
>   'null'.

What could be the possible solution for this??Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that's releasing memory? Just let it go out of scope.

Comment: You don't manually manage memory in JavaScript

Comment: So I don't need to do var oneDay=null???

Comment: Why are you redeclaring oneday

Comment: Try this: 
oneDay = null;

Comment: I'm deallocating the memory occupied by oneDay

Comment: What @Jain said; that's the actual cause of your error.

Comment: @MANOJ learn the basics! http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks

Comment: And no, you are **not** deallocating memory with that code.

Comment: Try this:
oneDay = null;
or
delete oneDay;

Comment: remove `var` and, if you like, leave `oneDay=null;`

Comment: Cheers!! My friend :)

Comment: What if I have $scope.days=OneDay;How can I deallocate $scope.days?

Comment: I'm not sure but it works for you
$scope.days = null  or delete $scope.days

Comment: Are you sure you are using JavaScript, not TypeScript? That error is not a JavaScript error.

Comment: I'm using typescript @Felix

Comment: Sorry, but storing `null` takes as much space as storing the number, so you've accomplished nothing whatsoever, even if you needed to care about memory management, which of course you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause: You are re declaring this variable that why you are getting this error.
Try this:

```
oneDay = null;
$scope.days = null
```

or

```
delete $scope.days
```

Comment: `delete oneDay` will do absoulutely nothing.

Comment: This accepted answer unfortunately is off the mark. Setting the variable to be null is absolutely useless (since storing `null` takes up the same amount of space as storing the number of milliseconds in a day), even if you needed to worry about memory management, which of course you don't.

Comment: My answer is okay after update null can deallocate the memory space of varible. Please read it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999604/best-way-to-deallocate-an-array-of-array-in-javascript

Comment: In that case, he is "deallocating" a complex object (an array). You are trying to "deallocate" a scalar (single value, primitive) by setting it a different scalar (null). Setting a scalar to null does not release anything, it just changes its value to null. There may be some extremely special cases where you need to help JS out with its GC by setting complex objects to null, but the real answer to this question, repeat very carefully after me, is **you do not need to do any allocation, or deallocation, or any other form of memory management in JavaScript**.

Comment: Also, read the answer from @SteveFenton, who ought to know what he's talking about with a rep of 60K. His answer should be marked as the accepted one.

Answer (score 8):

Memory is managed for you in JavaScript.

All modern browsers use a mark-and-sweep algorithm to detect unreachable objects (some older browsers use a reference-counting algorithm, which fails to collect objects where there is a reference loop as there will always be a reference) *.

As soon as an object can no longer be referenced it is eligible for garbage collection (although garbage collection will happen "at some point", not immediately).

On the whole, you don't need to concern yourself with memory management in JavaScript or TypeScript - unless you have a measurable problem.

(* From Pro TypeScript, p168-170)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this valuable info @Steve